# Rmarkdown does not work with raleway latex package

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, tinytex

I'm not able to knit file with this header:

```
---
title: ' '
author: ' '
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage[default]{raleway}
---
```

I'm getting error using `tinytex` distribution.

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `ly1enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
```

Output of `xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')`:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134), RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czechia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czechia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czechia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
  LC_TIME=Czech_Czechia.1250    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 digest_0.6.19   evaluate_0.13   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.6.0  grDevices_3.6.0 highr_0.8       htmltools_0.3.6
  jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.23      magrittr_1.5    markdown_0.9    methods_3.6.0   mime_0.6        Rcpp_1.0.1      rmarkdown_1.12 
  stats_3.6.0     stringi_1.4.3   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.13    tools_3.6.0     utils_3.6.0     xfun_0.7        yaml_2.2.0     

Pandoc version: 2.6
```

When removing `\usepackage[default]{raleway}` everything works fine. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Have you installed the `raleway` package to a directory which is available/accessible for `LaTeX`?

Comment: It seems so as `tinytex::tlmgr_install('raleway')` returns `tlmgr install raleway
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: raleway`

Comment: Well, it was `tinytex::tlmgr_install("ly1")` what helped. Anyway, thanks for an idea what may have been wrong.